Rendering to movie vs rendering from frames
I ran into a looping problem and thought it was my animation setup. Turns out it might be a rendering issue:

I rendered a movie directly from the Blender General (3D) interface to a movie. The rendered output loops correctly.

I then rendered frames from Blender General (3D), and brought them into the Video Editor to render. The final output has a jerking action in it when it loops at the end.


In both scenarios, they will loop correctly in the viewport before rendering. But only the one finally rendered in the Video Editor is causing the jerking action.
In both scenarios, I used the following similar settings:

H.264
30fps
MP4 Container
18 keyframe interval

Any clues as to what might be going on?
The 3D file:

The Video Editor file:


The sequence seems to have the first frame missing(when I render it and use Find Missing Files to replace the frames). Just delete the strip, set current frame to 1 and import the sequence again.

Thank you for this! I deleted the strip and made sure that it started at 1 and ended in 4. However, it still caused a jerkiness when I played it back in the Quicktime Player. I also ran the file in a web browser with a loop: and it didn't cause this issue. So the problem could also be my codec settings and/or my QT player. Will investigate further.
